# Project File downgrade from VS2010 to VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I just created a VB.Net Application with Visual Studio 2010 in other computer and I want to copy it so I can modify the system at home. I'm using VS2008 at home. After I copied it, I did this: Which I found on the internet

- Format Version 10.00 ( Changed from 11.00 to 10.00)
- # Visual Studio 2008 (Changed from 2010 to 2008)

When I opened my system in my computer, I have error all over my window forms. All of my window forms have this error

> 'IContainer' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel'.
>
> 'ISupportInitialize' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel'

Most of the error I see is this. I have searched the internet for the right solution. If anyone could tell me what should I do. I would greatly appreciate it.

> 'IContainer' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel'.
>
> 'ISupportInitialize' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' 
>   'GeneratedCodeAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.CodeDom.Compiler'. 
>   'EditorBrowsableAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel'.
>   'GeneratedCodeAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.CodeDom.Compiler'.

Comment: http://stevedunns.blogspot.com/2010/02/tool-to-switch-project-files-between.html

Comment: Visual Studio has a very liberal license, you are allowed to install it on any machine you own as long as there is no scenario where they are in use at the same time.  Clearly you'll want to take advantage of that, update your home machine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [first link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951089) that Google offers this is what you should do:

> Remove the project's reference to the 'System' assembly (System.dll),
>   rebuild the project, then add the reference back to System.dll.